# Wrong value from expand column (Power Query)

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm having a problem with power query where the values from a column comes wrong when I expand it.

Below is the value before expand it

[image: Column value]

And here is the value after I expand the column

[image: Column vaue after expanded]

For some reason the value is identical to a previous column ([Cota Atual])

Comment: FIXED IT

It was missing a Table.buffer() before the join so power query could do it properly

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a nested table in one of the columns as highlighted below in your right side table. Can you delete that before the join and try to see if it solves the issue.
[image: Issue]

Comment: I have tried to delete it before the join but it does not solve the issue. It still get me the wrong value

Comment: Is it possible for you to reproduce the issue in a small scale? Otherwise it is difficult to debug

Comment: I have fixed the issue. The logic was right, but I found out that power query does not deal well with nested operations so I had to add a Table.buffer() on the nested table before the join. After that it worked just right.